# Multiple data sources with the same type of entities but different database

Tags: mysql, hibernate-mapping

I have the same data to be submitted into two different MySQL databases. As soon as it updates, inserts, deletes in one, it should immediately update, insert, delete in the other or else rollback both.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="t1Datasource"
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>content/name.hbm.xml</value>
            <value>conten/desg.hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Should I create a new session for the other database or is there other process?

Comment: If you want to simulate this replication from your application layer, then you are looking at distributed transactions, that are always tricky to handle. If you prefer to do this at the DB layer through triggers on the tables, then it becomes a bit simpler. Much better is to employ some MySQL replication strategies.

Answer (score 0):

if i were to do this, i would have `2 connection managers`, 1 pointing to `databaseA` and the other to `databaseB`, then in my data access layer, set `auto commit` to false, `transact at databaseA`, then if transaction is successful, i would `transact to`databaseB, then if successful, `commit connection 1 then commit connection 2` else rollback both